# Where can I run MDX Queries on macOS?

Tags: mdx, data-warehouse, olap, olap-cube

I searched and found that there is only SQL server (Microsoft) that can execute MDX queries, and unfortunately it is not compatible with macOS. Are there relative apps or environments that I could install on an IDE that could understand MDX query?

Answer (score 0):

I think you could try [icCube](https://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/user_guide/running_iccube/server.php). As I see they support MAC OS.